# MsSql pivot - поворот таблицы

Tags: sql-server

Мне нужно немного повернуть таблицу изменив измерения. Я использую `Pivot`, но проблема в том, что я не пойму, как выбрать все значения в столбце для селекта как названия столбцов и для обработки `pivot`. Нужно вместо:

```
select [2001], [2002], [2003]
from table
pivot(
MAX(Value)
for date in ([2001], [2002], [2003])
)as pvt
```

Что-то типа:

```
select (select date from table)
from table
pivot(
MAX(value)
For date in (select date from table)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PIVOT можно сделать только для заранее известного набора данных. Динамически генерировать столбцы в нем нельзя. Хотите динамической генерации - пишите хранимую процедуру или функцию.

Comment: т.е. без использования pivot самому поворачивать таблицу так как надо?
Или можно пихнуть в pivot готовый набор названий столбцов, собранный заранее(только вот как сделать и в какой форме если это реально)?

Comment: Можно сделать хранимую процедуру, которая сначала определит набор столбцов (выберет все года), потом сгенерирует SQL и выполнит его, выдав таблицу с нужными данными. 
Ну, например, как здесь:
http://hashcode.ru/questions/42644/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%82-%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8